# Toggle text Collapse to Expand

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to change "Collapse" text to "Expand" on click of `h2` tag. at the same time I am applying "active" class to `h2` tag. using following directive, which is working fine, but now I am clueless about how to change "collapse" text to Expand on `h2` tag click

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="panel-title" toggleclass>My Tandem URL</h2>
<a class="collapse-arrow">Collapse</a>
```

**js**

```
.directive("toggleclass", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("click", function () {
                element.toggleClass('active');
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Can anyone plz help..

Comment: Replace **Collapse** with **{{text}}** and in the link function do scope.text = "Expand" (or "Collapse)

Comment: Since this directive has no new (isolated) scope, you are polluting the scope with the `text` model and you are unable to have more than one collapse-arrow in the same template (scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 
If you want to do DOM manipulation in your directive you could change the contents of the element by doing:

```
var link = element.find('a');
link.text(link.text() === 'Collapse' ? 'Expand' : 'Collapse')`.
```

Using `html` instead of `text` also works.
You have to move the link inside the h2 to have the directive see the link.

Another approach is having the link text changed via the scope, but then you need to have a template and bind the link text to the directive scope. Then you have to wrap both elements in a directive.
This may make the solution a bit too big for this simple use case...

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion on making up an directive: encapsulates html and behaivor inside: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rustam/qbsLuhmr/) .

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
        .directive('togglable', function () {

            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                template: '<div><h2 class="panel-title" ng-class="{ active: isCollapsed }" ng-click="toggle()" ng-transclude></h2><a class="collapse-arrow">{{ isCollapsed ? "Expand" : "Collapse"}}</a></div>',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                scope: false,
                controller: function ($scope) {

                    $scope.isCollapsed = false;

                    $scope.toggle = function () {
                        $scope.isCollapsed = !$scope.isCollapsed;
                    };
                }
            };
        });
```

Key features:
- no manual DOM manipulaton;
- uses transclude feature;

Such a directive is easy to use:

```html
<togglable>My Tandem URL</togglable>
```

Comment: actually it requries using     scope: {} , otherwise  several directives used on the same page share same $scope.isCollapsed  state

Comment: Additionally the `$scope.isCollapsed = false;` statement can be removed because `undefined` is also falsy in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your app works, maybe you can try this:

HTML:

```
<h2 class="panel-title" ng-class="{'active': expand}" toggleclass>My Tandem URL</h2>
<a class="collapse-arrow" ng-hide="expand">Collapse</a>
<a class="collapse-arrow" ng-show="expand">Expand</a>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCTRL', function($scope) {

  $scope.expand = false;

})
.directive("toggleclass", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          scope.expand = !scope.expand;
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uqbc9asf/